# How to make dropdown list behave as a select for if/else purposes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a regular dependent selects, as in the code below:

HTML:

```
<select id="select_ciudad">
<option>Madrid</option>
<option>Barcelona</option>


<select id="select_act">
<option>A</option>  
<option>B</option>  


<select id="select_act2" style="display:none">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>

</select>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
 $("#select_ciudad").change(function() {
  if ($("#select_ciudad").val()=="Madrid") {
    $("#select_act").show();
    $("#select_act2").hide(); 
    }

else if ($("#select_ciudad").val()=="Barcelona") {
        $("#select_act2").show();
            $("#select_act").hide();
    };
});
```

But now I don't want to use a select anymore and I'm substituting it by a css unordered list, doing something like:

NEW HTML:

```
<section class="main">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown"          tabindex="1">
                    <span>Ciudad</span>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Madrid</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Barcelona</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            ​</div>
        </section>
```

And the thing is now I cannot make the JS work the same way to do something when I click on any of the options (list elements). Do someone knows how to do it?

Comment: That HTML is not your official, is it? Closing `</select>` tags are missing.

Comment: Google "custom select box." Then again, _why_ are you replacing the native element?

Comment: It is not the official (copy/paste mistake). I replaced the native element because I do not want a select box anymore, but something like the from/to boxes in, for instance, http://www.edreams.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign values to each of the `<li>` elements using a `data-` attribute. Then you can bind a click handler to each `<a>` element and use the value from the parent `<li>` element in your if-else statement.

But I recommend avoiding the if-else statement by using CSS classes.

First add the `data-` attributes to the `<li>` elements. These values represent selectors that identify the elements that should be shown for that option.

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li data-selector=".group-madrid"><a href="#">Madrid</a></li>
    <li data-selector=".group-barcelona"><a href="#">Barcelona</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then put CSS classes on the elements you want to show/hide. Use one class (in this case "group") to identify all such elements. Then give each element a second class (in this case either "group-madrid" or "group-barcelona") to tie them to one of the items above.

```
<select id="select_act" class="group group-madrid">
    ...
</select>
<select id="select_act2" class="group group-barcelona">
    ...
</select>
```

Then bind an on-click handler to the `<a>` elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dropdown').on('click', '>li>a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.group').hide();
        $($(this).parent('li').attr('data-selector')).show();
    }).children('li:first').children('a:first').click();
});
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TsE9L/4/)

The code above actually uses event delegation, binding a single on-click handler to the `<ul>` element, but when the callback is executed, `this` refers to the `<a>` element that was clicked.

In case it's not obvious, the reason I would do it this way is that you can add more groups, or more elements to an existing group, without having to change the JavaScript code at all, as shown in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TsE9L/5/).